# Possible to copy Android KeyStore from one phone to another?

Tags: android, keystore

We are developing an app which stores secrets using Android KeyStore.
It is important for us that these secrets cannot be replicated to other devices. The user indirectly pays for the utility of this secret and if it can be copied to another device then our customers can technically avoid paying us.

We have tried to install a new phone using google built in "copy data and apps from old phone". In this case we didn't see the secrets transferring from the old phone to the new one. We have however gotten reports about customers using custom apps to copy data from one phone to the other where the secrets "work" on the new phone.

Are there any apps out there that can copy the phones Keystore into a new phones Keystore? Should we be worried about this?

Comment: Post the code how you create the secret in Android KeyStore, otherwise it is not quite clear what keystore and secret you are talking about.

Comment: It's more of a general question. But we use `keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);` and a KeyGenerator to store our secret key. We then use this key so we can store encrypted data in our regular app data and decrypt it in runtime using this key.

Comment: I am sorry but that code line doesn't say anything and because it used an custom constant you don't even know what type of keystore it creates. Please post the code that creates the key pair or whatever you do otherwise it is not really possible to tell you what may go wrong.